# Can't Access dSpace Web Interface using Public IP Ubuntu Apache Tomcat

Tags: networking, apache2, tomcat

I have recently configured **dSpace Repository system** in Ubuntu 16.04. Currently it is working fine locally using

> localhost:8080/jspui

But when I configured Public IP Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx using method Manual and try to access it from another Network It gives me the Error

```
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.
```

NOTE: I can ping IP from another Network but can't access its Web Inteface.

Is there any kind of Firewall rule in Ubuntu to configure in order to access dSpace Publicly that I am missing?

Comment: yes, it need to add rules on ubuntu firewall(you may skip this for testing) as well as on you router, After check the port is open or not from outside of network

Comment: Actually, There is no router in between My dSpace Server & ISP. I have a dedicated CIR connection and configured IPs directly I can use Internet, I can ping its Public IP from another Network, I know its a bad Idea but currently this is my requirement.

Comment: @Nullpointer can you lead me to configure Firewall Rule that you are talking about ?

Comment: you can check whether port is open or not from outside using `telnet <ip> <port>` or http://ping.eu/port-chk/

Comment: @Nullpointer yes Required Port 8080 is closed, How to open it ?

Comment: shate the output of `netstat -atun | grep <port>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65817/discussion-between-mohiyo-deen-and-nullpointer).